# Best band ratios in Aster data

Tags: band, aster

I am interested in the determination of lithology by using ASTER band ratio. I try to a lot of band ratio (for example RGB 4/8, 4/2, 8/9) but I didn't get a good result.

What is the best band ratio to distinguish sedimentary rocks and other lithologies in ASTER data?

The discrimination of sedimentary rocks is especially important for me.